# Sobrescrita de classes?

Tags: css, css3

tenho o seguinte css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.divCheckBox {
    width: 140px;
    height: 34px;
}
.divCheckBox .valor {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 34px;
    top: 0;
}
.divCheckBox .checkBox {
    display: none;
}
.divCheckBox .labelCheckBox {
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.divCheckBox .labelCheckBox:before {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .divCheckBox .labelCheckBox {
    background-color: blue;
}
.divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .divCheckBox .labelCheckBox:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

E o seguinte html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CheckBox Round</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_css/checkBoxRound.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="?" method="post">
  <div class="divCheckBox">
    <label class="valor">SIM</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ca" id="ca" class="checkBox">
    <label for="ca" class="labelCheckBox"></label>
    <label class="valor">NÃO </label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Quando eu rodo, e clico no labelCheckBox, tecnicamente deveria alterar sua cor para azul e a bolinha de dentro correr para a direita. Mas não está acontecendo.

No entanto, embora o nome da classe esteja correto, caso eu retire

```
.divCheckBox
```

Da estrutura abaixo

```
.divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .divCheckBox .labelCheckBox {
    background-color: blue;
}
.divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .divCheckBox .labelCheckBox:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

Ficando,

```
.checkBox:checked + .labelCheckBox {
    background-color: blue;
}
.checkBox:checked + .labelCheckBox:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

Então funciona.

Onde estará esse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seletor `+` é para selecionar o próximo elemento "irmão". Neste caso, do jeito que você montou o interpretador leu:

```
.divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .divCheckBox .labelCheckBox
```

> Selecione todos elementos com a classe `.divCheckBox`, depois selecione todos os descendentes com a classe `.checkBox` e que estejam com `:checked`, em seguida procure o próximo irmão (`+`) que contenha a classe `.divCheckBox` (foi aqui que você cometeu o equívoco), e em seguida procure os descendentes com a classe `.labelCheckBox`.

Ou seja, pelo seu HTML, não existe esse irmão `.divCheckBox` do `.checkBox`.

Para corrigir isso, basta retirar o segunda `.divCheckBox`. Segue abaixo seu exemplo corrigido:

```css
.divCheckBox {
    width: 140px;
    height: 34px;
}
.divCheckBox .valor {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 34px;
    top: 0;
}
.divCheckBox .checkBox {
    display: none;
}
.divCheckBox .labelCheckBox {
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.divCheckBox .labelCheckBox:before {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .labelCheckBox {
    background-color: blue;
}
.divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .labelCheckBox:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CheckBox Round</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_css/checkBoxRound.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="?" method="post">
  <div class="divCheckBox">
    <label class="valor">SIM</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ca" id="ca" class="checkBox">
    <label for="ca" class="labelCheckBox"></label>
    <label class="valor">NÃO </label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado.